# Is there a search history feature for VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code I'm missing the ability to re-run an earlier search. A hit in a search often leads me to quickly check out something else by doing a new search, but after that side-trip I want to be able to the return to the original search results. Is that feature hiding in plain sight, or if not is there an extension that provides it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Page up/down</kbd> will work on Windows when the search panel input has focus to cycle through recent search terms.  But they won't necessarily bring back the actual search results, but you don't have to re-enter the search terms anyway.

ADDED June, 2018:

As of v1.24 you can do the same for the replace terms:

> **Replace term history in Search view**
>
> You can now navigate to your previous replace terms in the Search
>   View.
>
> Alt+Up navigates backward in the history.
>
> Corresponding command is `search.replaceHistory.showPrevious`.
>
> Alt+Down navigates forward in the history.
>
> Corresponding command is `search.replaceHistory.showNext`.

From [May, 2018 release notes: replace term history](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_replace-term-history-in-search-view)

Comment: Accepting this answer because it led me to the one that works for me on a Mac: alt(option)/up-down. Thanks!

Comment: alt + up/down arrow works in linux (ubuntu) as well. wish this was more intuitive, though. perhaps a mouse thing (yeah, yeah, i know, but when you are new, it is nice to *not* have to remember all the shortcuts).